# Upload image in public folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to insert image in database using laravel 5.4. It works. But when I search that directory then it does not appear there. I also want to validate only images should be upload and size.
Thanks for advance.

My Controller function is here

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Hash;
use App\User;
class regController extends Controller
{

public function create(Request $request)
{
    $this-> validate(request(),[
    'name' => 'required',
    'email'=> 'required',
    'type' => 'required',
    'image' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6', 
    ]);

    $request['password'] = bcrypt($request -> password);

    $User = new User($request->input()) ;
    if($file = $request->hasFile('image')) {

        $file = $request->file('image') ;

        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
        return Storages::putFile('public/images',$request->file('image'));
        $destinationPath = public_path().'images/' ;
        $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
        $User->image = $fileName ;
    }

    $user = 
          User::create(request(['name','email','type','image','password']));
    return redirect('login');
}
```

Comment: `return` terminates rest of the code, it is still `Storage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
// Validation
$this->validate($request, [
   'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|max:10240' // size in kelobytes this equals 10 mb
]);

 $User = new User() ;
 $User->password = bcrypt($request->password);
 $User->name = $request->name;
 $User->type = $request->type;
 $User->email = $request->email;
 $filename = $this->getFileName($request->image);
 $request->image->move(base_path('public/images'), $filename);
 $User->image = $fileName;
 $$User->save();
 return back()->with('success','Image Upload successful');
```

I just forgot to show you how to implement `getFileName` function to generate a unique filename sorry about that, in your controller you can define it as protected method like so:

```
protected function getFileName($file)
{
   return str_random(32) . '.' . $file->extension();
}
```

Comment: File name shows in database but does not in public/images directory ......

Comment: Your form needs to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` add to your form element

Comment: It shows
 "BadMethodCallException
Method [getFileName] does not exist."

Comment: Its working . thanks but in database it shows C:\xampp\tmp\phpA9B9.tmp. My file name dose not show

Comment: I believe something wrong in how you save the filename. Do you save it like this `$User->image = $fileName;`

Comment: $filename = $this->getFileName($request->image); 
 $request->image->move(base_path('public/images'), $filename);

        $user = User::create(request(['name','email','type','image','password']));
        return redirect('login');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159326/discussion-between-mithun-and-amr-aly).

Comment: Check my updated answer. this all you need to save your user. if it's not working we will continue in chat

Comment: @Mithun Anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are tryin to do smth like this:

```
public function fileUpload(Request $request)

{

    $this->validate($request, [

        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',

    ]);


    $image = $request->file('image');

    $input['imagename'] = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $destinationPath = public_path('/images');

    $image->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);


    $this->postImage->add($input);


    return back()->with('success','Image Upload successful');

}
```

Comment: It shows error  "FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null "

Comment: Are you passing image to the url?. does your form tag have enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute?

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url('registration') }}">    

<input type="file" class="btn btn-file btn-default form-control" id="imgInp" name="image" style="">